# Redirect to blank page after sending data with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a survey webpage that if users done it , I will send the data they give (as `$_SESSION` from the other pages) and I will change his/her status to 0 (They can't do the survey after that with his/her login info.).

All of these are doing with `PDO`. But why the page always redirects to a white blank page?

Here is my code

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) 
{
header("location:index.php");
}
?>

<?php
require_once "condb.php";
?>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['BTN_P2']))
{
  $_SESSION['problem'] = $_POST['problem'];
  if ($_SESSION['problem'] == "yes"){header("location:survey_3.php");}
else
{
  $sql="INSERT INTO data(time,suggest,phone,eat,problem) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
  $stm=$cn->prepare($sql);
  $stm->bindParam("1",$_SESSION['time']);
  $stm->bindParam("2",$_SESSION['suggest']);
  $stm->bindParam("3",$_SESSION['phone']);
  $stm->bindParam("4",$_SESSION['eat']);
  $stm->bindParam("5",$_SESSION['problem']);

  try 
  {
    $stm->execute();
      try 
      {
       $sqlstatus="INSERT INTO login(status) VALUES(0)";
       $stmt=$cn->prepare($sqlstatus);
       $stmt->execute();
       echo "Finish!";
       header('location:finish.php');
      } 
      catch (Exception $error) 
      {
        echo $error->getTraceAsString();
      }
  } 
  catch (Exception $e) 
  {
    echo $e->getTraceAsString();
  }
}
}
?>
```

What I am missing?

Edit #1 : Verifying how `$_SESSION['user']` comes from.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['BTN_ENTER']))
{
  $username=$_POST['username'];
  $password=$_POST['password'];
  $hashed_password=password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    try
    {
      $stmt = $cn->prepare("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username=:username LIMIT 1");
      $stmt->execute(array(':username'=>$username));
      $result=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
        {
          if(password_verify($password, $result['password']))
          {
            if ($result['status']==1)
              {
                $_SESSION['user']=$result['name'];
                header('location:survey.php');
              }
          }
        }
     }
     catch(PDOException $e)
     {
       echo $e->getMessage();
     }
}
```

Comment: Most likely because `$_SESSION['user']` is never set. Can you show the code that sets `$_SESSION['user']`?

Comment: How do you know it's redirecting to a blank page and not simply having an error that you are not seeing by because you are not viewing errors using `error_reporting(E_ALL);`? Are errors turned on for viewing?

Comment: @Fredster I've edit to verify how `$_SESSION['user']` comes from.

Comment: But do you have error reporting on? Not messages you have created, actual error reporting.

Comment: Make sure if your database connection is properly being establish

Comment: Does the column `name` exist in the table `login`? Or did you mean `username`?

Comment: @Rasclatt I've got an error already and fixed it. It said "Finish!" but nothing in my tables.

Comment: @Fredster I use name column to show user on the top of the page that you are logging in as who. To show like "You are logged in as `<?=$_SESSION['name']?>`"

Comment: @Saquib Lari I've used `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and no error. So it should be connected properly.

Comment: Ok! What about the column `status`? Does it also exist? Is it `=1` for the user you are testing?

Comment: @Fredster I use `status` column to check that that user has a right to do the survey or not. If it's `1` means you can do. If it's `0` means you did it already. If it's `2` means you can't do because administrator rights. This column doesn't have `=` like your example. I've only number.

Comment: Well you didn't execute the last statement before it says `"Finished"`, you only bound the parameter....

Comment: Also, you don't need to bind parameter since you hardcode what goes in there...unless you don't trust your own input. Just execute the query there. The only place you need to prepare and bind is when the user has touched, in some way, the value that is being inserted. Otherwise you can just do the query.

Comment: @Rasclatt after `$stmt->execute();` Nothing happened. I will update my codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try and break your scripts into functions / methods to make it easier to work with, read, reuse, etc. When you make a function, you can try it manually by itself before you implement it. Once you confirm the function works by itself, then you throw it into the logic and if something fails, you know it's not that function:

**/functions/suggestEatingProblem.php**

```
<?php
function suggestEatingProblem($con,$array)
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `data` (`time`,`suggest`,`phone`,`eat`,`problem`) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
        $query = $con->prepare($sql);
        # Since you are not really doing anything special with your parameters
        # just do the array into the execute function, it's more straight forward
        $query->execute($array);
    }
```

**/functions/addLoginStatus.php**

```
<?php
function addLoginStatus($con,$val)
    {
        # Don't need to prepare, just query
        $con->query("INSERT INTO login (`status`) VALUES({$val})");
    }
```

**/functions/verifyUser.php**

```
<?php
function verifyUser($con,$username,$password)
    {
        $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT `password`,`name` FROM login WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->execute(array($username));
        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if(empty($result['password']))
            return false;

        $isValid = password_verify($password, $result['password']);
        return ($isValid)? $result['name'] : false;
    }
```

**/config.php**

```
<?php
# Create some helpful constants
define('DS',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('ROOT_DIR',__DIR__);
define('FUNCTIONS',ROOT_DIR.DS.'functions');
# Start session
session_start();
# Start database
require_once(ROOT_DIR.DS."condb.php");
```

**/whatever.php**

```
<?php
# Add config at top
require_once(__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config.php');
# Add our functions to be used
require_once(FUNCTIONS.DS.'suggestEatingProblem.php');
require_once(FUNCTIONS.DS.'addLoginStatus.php');
# If no session, redirect
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
    # Make sure to stop your script if you are done with the page
    exit;
}
# Check if submission
if(isset($_POST['BTN_P2'])) {
    # Assign problem (trim it)
    $_SESSION['problem'] = trim($_POST['problem']);
    # If yes
    if($_SESSION['problem'] == "yes") {
        # Redirect and stop the script execution
        header("Location: survey_3.php");
        exit;
    }
    else {
        # Just do one "try" here...
        try {
            # Run your function here
            suggestEatingProblem($cn,array(
                $_SESSION['time'],
                $_SESSION['suggest'],
                $_SESSION['phone'],
                $_SESSION['eat'],
                $_SESSION['problem']
            ));
            # Run your second function here
            addLoginStatus($cn,'0');
            # Redirect. You can not put content before you redirect, so
            # remove the "Finished" echo
            header('Location: finish.php');
            exit;
        } 
        catch (PDOException $e){
            echo 'Error occurred: '.$e->getTraceAsString();
        }
    }
}
else {
    echo 'No request sent.';
}
```

**Validation portion:**

```
# Add function (see the other example to add the config)
require_once(FUNCTIONS.DS.'verifyUser.php');
# If there is a submission
if(isset($_POST['BTN_ENTER'])) {
    try {
        # Fetch the name (or false)
        $user = verifyUser($cn,trim($_POST['username']),trim($_POST['password']));
        # If not false
        if($user) {
            # Assign the value
            $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
            # Redirect and stop execution of script
            header('Location: survey.php');
            exit;
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $d) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```